# What orbital maneuver(s) did the SOHO have to execute for halo orbit insertion?

Tags: orbital-maneuver, halo-orbit

I started, but did not complete, Classical Mechanics as an undergraduate, decades ago so I will not understand a highly technical answer.

I am writing a novel where an astronaut needs to execute HOI (Halo Orbit Insertion) manually, and want to describe it with some basic details.

Comment: You can see a 3D plot of SOHO's travel and insertion into a halo orbit in the question [Is this what station keeping maneuvers look like, or just glitches in data? (SOHO via Horizons)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/16644/12102) Here is a [detailed list of events](https://sohowww.nascom.nasa.gov/soc/soho_events/SOHO-Spacecraft-Events.pdf) `FEB 14 1996 45 75 17:00 Halo Orbit Insertion Manoeuvre (HOI)`

Comment: @uhoh, that is great information.  Much of it I am still trying to figure out what it means.  Do you know what it means on the SOHO event list, "Momentum Management; +3500/+600/+1000" specifically what to the numbers refer to?  I assume MCC1 X-1 Burn means mid-course correction, but what does the 1 and the X-1 Burn mean?

Comment: Those are great questions! There's no limit to the number of (good) questions you can ask here, why not choose two or three of those and post a new question?