# Cis-L2 Libration Point Halo Orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, simulation, cislunar, queqiao

Queqiao became the first satellite to orbit the Cis-L2 libration point (far side of the moon). Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chang%27e_4

Does anyone have any insight on how to model this orbit in STK?

Comment: Cool question! As I mention in [this long-winded answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33235/12102) a halo orbit around an Earth-Moon Lagrange point is really a Earth orbit that happens to be in a 1:1: resonance with the Moon. (Watch the Kepler Telescope video there for an analogy) If STK allows for Earth orbits that far out and it includes a real, accurate ephemeris of the Moon, then maybe it's possible. A simple, approximate orbit propagator like SGP4 couldn't because it only [approximates](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23810/12102) the effect of lunar gravity.

Comment: However, the hard part of the problem is *finding the orbit first!* Without a known starting state vector, you will have to search a seven dimensional space ($\mathbf{x}, $\mathbf{v}, $\mathbf{x}, t) to find the specific orbit in question, seven rather than six because the Moon's orbit is so elliptical that CR3BP may not be good enough.